# Getting Co-ordinates of Image PlaceHolders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am working on an application wherein i need to layout multiple images on a sheet of size 8X10. The requirement is to save the co-ordinates of the placeholders used to put images while creating the templates so that when displaying to the end users, these placeholders can be filled with the actual images. I need to implement this using ASP.Net but I am not sure how to implement this.

Can anyone suggest some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating HTML at the end, you will have difficulty using x/y coordinates for image positioning unless you also use x/y/width/height positioning for all text areas in the final document.

If you do go with the coordinates system, you could build a jQuery UI to allow users to drag/drop/resize layers (divs) and enter text in them, then upload it to the server as a list of layers(x,y,width,height,content).

To render, just loop through the layers and write out the HTML. For the images, you'll probably need [a server-side image resizing library](http://imageresizing.net) so that you can ensure they fit within their assigned spaces.